# can't install rmagick on mac lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

when I try to install rmagick it keep coming up the error:

error: http://rubygems.org/does not appear to be a repository
error: could not find gem rmagick locally or in a repository

another question is how can I check has rmagick installed or not
I try rmagick -v it say command not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it!

We used rmagick far too long. The project is unmaintained, switch to MiniMagick before it is too late.

The big issue here, is that Rmagick isn't compatible with newer ImageMagick.

### Update

I spoke too soon. They found someone to take it over, but look at [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick). 90% of the files haven't been touched in nearly five years.

I have it installed on my machine.

The steps I took were:

```
brew install ImageMagick
gem install rmagick
```

However that was nearly a year ago, a colleague couldn't get it working last week with updated ImageMagick, now I see on GitHub they may have fixed his issue, so best of luck. I also remember fumbling around with using a non LLVM version of GCC to compile it. But I feel like that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: try the edge gem from github, and install imagemagick via brew? Or possible find the source for last compatible ImageMagick, download all the dependecies, configure your build correctly and hope for the best compiling it on your own. I've compiled ImageMagick from source in the past to get it to play nice with Rmagick, theres a whole sea of gists claiming to help you do just that.

Comment: would you mind show me the step or any instruction on line? sorry, i am a beginner.

Comment: its hard to say. i know you need a non LLVM compiler last time i checked. Do you have homebrew installed?

Comment: no, I don't think so,  I try to work on a project that someone else build around 2 years ago, and this project require all below isntalled: paperclip

dragonfly

authlogic

 sqlite3-ruby 

uuid

rmagick 

thin or mongrel 

nokogiri

rack-cache

pony

tiny_mce

Comment: install brew, and then `brew install ImageMagick` then try `gem install rmagick`

Comment: looks like your Gemfile is out of date too.

Comment: now I just can't install paperclip and rmagick, come out with same error message that I state before.

Comment: it come up with same error again when I try to install brew. why?

Comment: what is?  http://rubygems.org/does i think something is configed wrong. Brew is not a ruby gem fyi.

Comment: I am installing brew now, will follow your step after install.

Comment: Does your Gemfile have `source 'https://rubygems.org'` or `source 'https://rubygems.org/does'`

Comment: i need update Xcode before install brew, take a bit time. can you help if I got problem install brew or rmagick?

Comment: sorry how can I check gemfile source?

Comment: look in your Gemfile. assuming you are using bundler.

Comment: install success. thanks for that. and when I try to install paperclip, it ask for update ruby to 1.9.2, should I do it or I can install older version of Paperclip? thanks

Comment: u can probably get by installing an older version, eventually consider upgrading everything to the 1.9.3 ruby. As rails drops support for older rubies when u get to 3.1+

Comment: All installed complete, now I need to import the project to my mac. do you have any instruction link on how to do that please?

Comment: done! please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763377/how-to-import-ruby-on-rails-project

Answer (score 1):

Barring "Don't Do It!" (sound advice if you can take it) you'll need to resort to Homebrew to install rmagick.