# How to import ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to import a project that someone else build 1 year ago, now my mac have already installed all below which include:

- `ruby, rails and mysql`
- `paperclip`
- `dragonfly`
- `authlogic`
- `sqlite3-ruby`
- `uuid`
- `rmagick`
- `thin or mongrel`
- `nokogiri`
- `rack-cache`
- `pony`
- `tiny_mce`

could any one tell how to import the project, or any link on line can help me?

Comment: You are wanting to install these things or already have? Some are merely gems and you only need to bundle. Others like rmagick require you to install a library first. You can do this using brew or macports

Comment: @Antarr Byrd : I did finish installed all of them, now just wonder how can I import the file of a project?

Comment: What do you mean by import? Are you simply looking to get a working development environment?

Comment: I got someone build the project on linux system, now I want to transfer them over to my mac. how?

Comment: What you need is an understanding of how rails projects are structured, and what are the files mean. Take a look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIjPt50X1qA I also strongly recommend that you familiarize yourself with the rails ecosystem by going through the [Rails Tutorial book online](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing called import a rails project, If you have ruby installed, the you could use `bundler` to manage your gems via the `Gemfile`

if your project is built with rails >= 3 then [read this](http://gembundler.com/)

if your project is build with rails < 3 [then read this](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html)

and once you are ready with the setup run

```
bundle install
```

which will install all the necessary gems, and if you already have a `Gemfile`, then simply run

```
bundle update
```